# Compiling docx with py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe, docx

I'm compiling a python script to .exe via py2exe. I originally started compiling it and the entire program ran fine aside from the Word document creation.

My logfile would give me: `ERROR: Could not close or save Word Document 'docName.docx' :`, so where I am supposed to be supplied an error message - I am not.

I started to think it could do with the missing modules in py2exe, reported as:

```
The following modules appear to be missing
['ICCProfile', '_imaging_gif', '_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata']
```

And then I noticed many people didn't care too much about these errors.

I looked in the docx package, located in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\docx-0.2.4-py2.7.egg\`, as installed by easy_install, and saw this docx-templates folder, which I am certain was not imported, so I wrote my setup.py referencing the docx-template I put in my build folder manually:

from distutils.core import setup
from glob import glob
import os
import py2exe

```
#templatePath = 'C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/docx-0.2.4-py2.7.egg/docx-template'

setup(
    console=['xmlpolicydocx-0.4.py'],
    options={ 
                'py2exe': 
                { 
                    'includes': ['docx', 'PIL', 'lxml.etree', 'lxml._elementpath', 'gzip']
                }
            },
    packages=[
          'docx-template'
          ],
    package_data={
          'docx-template': [
              '_rels/*',
              'docProps/*',
              'word/theme/*.xml',
              'word/*.xml'
          ],
      },
    )
```

Yet I still have no luck in getting docx to work when compiled via py2exe. Any suggestions or methods of debugging I can take to take another look at solving this problem?

Comment: I suggest you to post an issue on https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx

Comment: I know you were specifically asking about py2exe but I have success compiling python scripts that implement docx library using [auto-py-to-exe](https://nitratine.net/auto-py-to-exe).


It utilizes pyinstaller and has a GUI which imo makes it a little more simple to use.